# Will it make a difference in performance to have multiple ques across different nodes?

Tags: java, python, amazon-ec2, queue, rabbitmq

Right now I'm working on how to improve efficiency of Rabbit.

For example:

#### Components:

- TCP Load Balancer
- Producers
- RabbitMQ cluster
- Consumers

#### Producers:

2-5 EC2 servers. Each server has a `logstash` installed and configured to send messages to the Rabbit. Nothing special about this. Only one requirements, messages needs to be persistent. (Just in case I/O is not an issue)

#### RabbitMQ Cluster:

2 EC2 servers. Lot of memory, cpu, good disk, nice bandwidth.

#### Consumers:

Very different number of consumers could be from 2-15. Consumers connects to the Load Balancer (ELB). Some of them uses `basic.get` some of them uses `basic.consume`. Requirements: `no_ack = False` , means all messages needs to be acknowledged.

Right now we have one queue that holds 95% of the traffic. My questions are:

- In case if I create an equal number of queues on each node in the rabbit cluster.(Right now I'm talking about how to distribute load of this one high traffic queue.) And each producer will publish messages to it's own queue. Consumers on the other end will subscribe to all queues and get messages from every queue. Will it increase performance?
- Also will 1 to 1 relationships between exchanges and queues make any difference in performance?
- Finally, what would you recommend in this case? ( consumers can't be dynamically configurred)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you're mirroring queues and using persistent messages, you're going to be harming performance. See my article on the [performance of RabbitMQ HA](http://globaldev.co.uk/2014/04/rabbitmq-from-the-front-line/) for details.

You're right though to consider more queues in order to improve throughput - each RabbitMQ is a single Erlang process so will only ever use one core. There's other Erlang processes of course that will help, but you are indeed bottlenecked by the single queue. The answer is the [consistent hash exchange type](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange/file/rabbitmq_v3_3_0/README.md) which will evenly distribute messages to each queue connected to it. YMMV but I'd imagine you'd want one queue per core of each server.

Comment: Just remembered this slide deck on the subject: http://www.slideshare.net/old_sound/rabbitmq-data-ingestion